# USB 3 vs Firewire 800

Tags: firewire, usb-3

We want to get some external hard-drives >= 1TB for copying large videos (10-500gb) and image sequences (1-150k files) in-house ala sneaker-net between Macs and PCs.

Does anyone have real-world experiences using either or both interfaces and can tell me which one is *generally* faster?

Please don't refer me to theoretical or specification speeds, as we all know those never hold up in the real world :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB 3.0 is (much) faster than Firewire. That's my experience.

**EDIT:**

As requested, performance over Firewire 800 is 2 - 3 times faster, which equates to 100 - <strike>150%</strike> 200% quicker.

This is my experience, with the files you'd normally find in a Windows 7 profile, including Temporary Internet Files, Documents, Pictures, etc.

Also, it's quicker than eSATA, but not by much in real terms.

Comment: In a similar scenario, specifically copying *many* smaller files? My experiences with USB 2.0 have always been deplorable in that area...

Comment: It's not that USB 2.0 is slow. Copying lots of small files is slow, regardless of the medium. And yes, I've had close to internal SATA speeds on USB 3.0.

Comment: I know my question is somewhat vague and I didn't specifically ask for it, but can you give more details than "much"? Any kind of _estimated_ figure would be nice such as 5-25%.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: 2–3 times faster actually equates to 100–200% quicker.

Comment: I have updated the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

The much touted USB 3.0 will only give a maximum throughput that the storage medium on both ends will allow! Unless you have several SATA HDD linked up in RAID 0 or a fast SSD on both ends, high throughput cannot be achieved.Therefore, super-fast data transfer cannot be achieved without a lot of very expensive fancy hardware.

Comment: Good point, but we have several RAID 0/1/1+0 systems along with SSD drives so that shouldn't be our main concern. On my laptop I'm currently getting ~50 MB/s from my SSD to a 2.5" 7200RPM drive in a USB 3.0 enclosure, although this SSD can go much faster.